# Restoring NFC Tag Behaviour

Tags: android, nfc

I am creating an app that detects some nfc tag with url. I have problem when I tap phone with the nfc tag, I am directly redirected to the url page. It doesn't show me app chooser. May be someone initialy set Chorme as default app to launch when phone encounters with such url based NFC tags. So my question is, is it possible to restore phones NFC settings so that it will ask me, which app to launch.

Intent Filter to Detect NFC Tag :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
  <data
       android:host="www.google.com"
       android:scheme="http" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            </intent-filter>
```

Intent Filter to detect launch of web page, I am expecting my app + browser softwares installed on device, show up in app chooser.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >  </action>                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" > </category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" > </category>
<data android:host="www.google.com"
      android:scheme="http" ></data>
</intent-filter>
```

But no app chooser show up, I am directly redirected to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some solution that is working in this case :

For first Intent :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <data
       android:host="google.com"
       android:scheme="http" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And for second intent :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" ></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" ></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" ></category>
    <data android:host="google.com"
      android:scheme="http" ></data>
</intent-filter>
```

just changed host name that worked for me.